# Regular expression to match variable=value but ignore trailing blanks and comments

Tags: regex

I am trying to parse a driver inf file and extract "variables" and "values" from sections.
I have come up with a basic regular expression:

```
"(.+?)\s*=\s*(.+)"
```

This matches the variable fine but then it matches everything after the equals and whitespace. In these files there may optionally be trailing comments that begin with a semicolon and I dont want those to match. I thought i'd try:

```
"(.+?)\s*=\s*(.+);?"
```

but it doesnt work. The other issue is that there may be white space before the semicolon which I also want to ignore but there may be white space within the value that I want to match. Here are some examples (using variable as the first match and value as the second):

Class=Display (the variable should be "Class" and the value "Display"

DefaultDestDir      = 11  ; system32 (variable="DefaultDestDir" and value="11")

cpuxyz    =   16483,au zy xy    open    ; comment (variable = "cpuxyz" and value = "16483,au zy xy    open")

I'm looking to expand my initial regular expression so that the "value" can cope with all of the above examples.

Comment: Try `(.+?)\s*=\s*([^;\n]+)\s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Negative Character Classes are Your Friend**

Lucky for you, I have some in my pocket today.

```
^([^=\s]+)[ ]*=[ ]*([^;\r\n]+)
```

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/vQ3iN1), look at the capture groups in the right pane.

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- In the first `(capture group)`, the negative character class `[^=\s]+` matches one or more chars that are not `=` or a whitespace character (which included newlines)
- `[ ]*` matches optional spaces. The brackets are not needed, they are there for clarity
- `=` matches the literal `=`
- `[ ]*` matches optional spaces.
- In the second `(capture group)`, the negative character class `[^;\r\n]+` matches one or more chars that are not `;` or newline characters

Comment: @m42 - What a great way to approach this and help me on my way to better use regular expressions. The only thing left are the trailing blanks at the end of the value but I could use a programming "trim" function to get rid of those rather than complicate the regexp further

Comment: You're very welcome, glad it helped. You can remove the last spaces by adding a negative lookbehind at the end to assert that the preceding char was not a space: `^([^=\s]+)[ ]*=[ ]*([^;\r\n]+)(?<! )` See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/gF9nR9)

Comment: @zx81 - Could you please explain in English what the last set of parentheses is doing? I know the second last set says "match the first character after the equals sign and optional white space that is not a semicolon or Return until ?????"

Comment: The `(?<! )` negative lookbehind asserts that what immediately precedes is not a space character. The space is the last char before closing the parentheses. Forces `[^;\r\n]+` to backtrack if it has matched trailing spaces (which it can). We can't add the space in `[^;\r\n]+` because we want him to be able to match `a b` See [Mastering Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: @zx81 - Just found an entry with a tab character and not getting any matches [link](http://regex101.com/r/pU5jH7/1). Any ideas why it's not matching the tab?

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would cature the variables and it's corresponding values into groups,

```
(.+?)\s*=\s*(.+?)\s*;
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pS0rB4)

**Explanation:**

- `(.+?)\s*` Matches and captures one or more characters from the beginning of the line upto the `\s` character.(`?` makes the regex engine to match the shortest possibility)
- `=` A literal `=` sign
- `\s*` Zero or more spaces.
- `(.+?)\s*` Matches and captures one or more characters from the beginning of the line upto the `\s` character.
- `;` A literal semi-colon.

Comment: @zx81 sorry, my laptop is going to poweroff.. I will get your after 7 hours.

Comment: That's not what I want to chat about, but on this pattern, one problem (as I see it) is that with this string `    My Long Variable=Display;` the variable will be `    My Long Variable` (including unlimited spaces at the front).

Comment: Its OK. No variables have white space, just values.

Comment: @Lembasts [if you got an working answer then don't forget to accept it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: I've just realised that the final \s*; will not remove white spaces within the value only white space that has a semicolon at the end. What if there was a line without a semi colon comment at the end - could you do \s*;*